# undefined method `destroy' for nil:NilClass(rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I get this error:

NoMethodError in CycleRoadsController#destroy

undefined method `destroy' for nil:NilClass(rails).

This is code from controller and theyt include a method 'destroy ':

```
        respond_to do |format|
      if @cycle_road.save
        format.html { redirect_to @cycle_road, notice: 'Cycle road was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @cycle_road }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @cycle_road.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @cycle_road.update(cycle_road_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @cycle_road, notice: 'Cycle road was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @cycle_road.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /cycle_roads/1
  # DELETE /cycle_roads/1.json
  def destroy
    @cycle_road.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to cycle_roads }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_cycle_road
      @cycle_road = CycleRoad.find(params[:id])
    end

    def cycle_road_params
      params.require(:cycle_road).permit(:name, :begin, :finish, :km, :description)
    end
end
```

Anybody know, what's wrong?

Comment: Could you post all code of the controller?

Comment: I put all code of the controller

Comment: as @Kirti Thorat said: you are tried to delete an item that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the instance variable `@cycle_road` before calling `destroy` on it.

Currently its `nil` as the error clearly says `undefined method 'destroy' for nil:NilClass`.

As per the shared controller code, you would need to add `destroy` action in the `before_action` callback of `set_cycle_road`

```
class CycleRoadController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_cycle_road, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  ## ...                                                         ^
  ##                                                          Add this
end
```

This callback would take care of setting the `@cycle_road` instance variable before calling `destroy` action.

Answer (score 0):

As the previous person mentioned it looks like @cycle_road is nil. Make sure that you have a before action:

```
class CycleRoadController < ApplicationController
  ...
  before_action :set_cycle_road
  ...
```

And ensure that it runs for your destroy method. ie.

```
before_action :set_cycle_road, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```